# On each mousemove, the draggable element positioning is getting reset to zero

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, draggable

I'm working on a component that moves a parts diagram around in a container. Right now everything works great on the first mousemove, but on the second the positioning styles are getting reset to zero.

I re-wrote the code outside of Vue and also made a codepen for your viewing.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/paytonburd/pen/WKqEjo

Code:

```
let diagram = document.getElementById('diagram')
let diagramImg = document.getElementById('diagram-image')
let startX;
let startY;
let walkX;
let walkY;
let dragging = false;

diagram.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  dragging = true;
  startX = e.pageX - diagram.offsetLeft;
  startY = e.pageY - diagram.offsetTop;
})

diagram.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!dragging) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  let x = e.pageX - diagram.offsetLeft;
  let y = e.pageY - diagram.offsetTop;

  walkX = x - startX
  walkY = y - startY
  console.log(walkX, walkY)

  diagramImg.style.top = walkY + 'px'
  diagramImg.style.left = walkX + 'px'
})

diagram.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  dragging = false;
})

diagram.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  dragging = false;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mouse down, you always set the `startX` and `startY` relative to the position of the `diagram`, which is always at 0, 0 and never moves.

I think what you want is to instead set them to relative to the current position of the diagram image instead:

```
let diagram = document.getElementById('diagram')
let diagramImg = document.getElementById('diagram-image')
let startX;
let startY;
let walkX;
let walkY;
let dragging = false;

diagram.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  dragging = true;
  //This is where it went wrong
  startX = e.pageX - diagramImg.offsetLeft; 
  startY = e.pageY - diagramImg.offsetTop; 
})

diagram.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!dragging) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  let x = e.pageX - diagram.offsetLeft;
  let y = e.pageY - diagram.offsetTop;

  walkX = x - startX
  walkY = y - startY
  console.log(walkX, walkY)

  diagramImg.style.top = walkY + 'px'
  diagramImg.style.left = walkX + 'px'
})

diagram.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  dragging = false;
})

diagram.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  dragging = false;
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqdzyq?editors=1111